# Создание JSON в php и его парсинг NSJSONSerialization

Tags: objective-c, php, json, синтаксический-анализ

Итак, ситуация следующая. Недавно начал изучать php. Хочу реализовать на php страничку в формате JSON, чтобы её считать с клиентского приложения под iOS. Соответственно, написал следующий код для php страницы (фрагмент):

```
$query="SELECT * FROM newslist";
    $news=mysql_query($query);
    if($news)
    {
        $jsonString = '';
        while($par=mysql_fetch_array($news))
        {
            $tmp = '
            {
              "title": '.$par['title'].',
              "description": '.$par['description'].',
              "text": '.$par['text'].',
              "date": '.$par['date'].'
            },
            ';
            $tmp2 = $jsonString;
            $jsonString = $tmp2.$tmp;
        }
        $endJsonString = '['.mb_substr($jsonString, 0, strlen($jsonString)-1). ']';
    }
    echo $endJsonString;
```

Которая по идее формирует и выводит страницу в формате JSON.  Далее, формирую в клиенте обращение к странице и её парсинг силами стандартного NSJSONSerialization:

```
NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://localhost:8888/news/data.php"]];
    NSData *response = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:nil error:nil];
    NSError *jsonParsingError = nil;
    NSArray *tmp = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:response options:0 error:&jsonParsingError];
```

Который эту страницу находит, но никак не разбирает (null).
Думаю, следует сразу оговориться, что клиент ранее использовался с сервером на Ruby on Rails, который генерил исправный JSON-файл с такой же структурой, который исправно парсился клиентом.

Так вот, собственно вопрос - как сделать правильно JSON страницу? Насколько я понял, косяк именно в ней.

Comment: да, косяк именно в том, что Вы вручную неправильный JSON выдаете! в РНР есть готовые методы, которые выдают валидный JSON json_encode/json_decode

Comment: все возможно. Можно и echo, можно и в файл все сохранять: fopen/fwrite

Comment: с выводом-проверкой скорее всего поможет curl http://localhost:8888/news/data.php > ~/Desktop/result.json из терминала

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Начнем, пожалуй с такого:

```
$query="SELECT * FROM newslist";
$news=mysql_query($query);
if($news)
   echo json_encode(mysql_fetch_array($news));
```